# Updating ipykernel or anything else causes linkerror and rollback

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, 64-bit, conda

conda update ipykernel -v

yields the following response. It's the same for any update or installation on any package via the anaconda prompt. Running as administrator.

On a side note, IDLE and pip tends to be much easier to use, but I would rather anaconda work.

I have tried 'conda clean all' and 'conda update all' to no avail.

```
Executing transaction: ...working... ===> UNLINKING PACKAGE: defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py37_0 <===
  prefix=D:\Anaconda3


===> LINKING PACKAGE: defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0 <===
  prefix=D:\Anaconda3
  source=D:\Anaconda3\pkgs\ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0


$ C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /c D:\Anaconda3\.tmpsme8hq3b.bat
==> cwd: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts <==
==> exit code: 1 <==
==> stdout <==

==> stderr <==
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.



An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0'.
LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>

Attempting to roll back.


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0 <===
  prefix=D:\Anaconda3


failed
An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0'.
LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>

Attempting to roll back.


Rolling back transaction: ...working... ===> REVERSING PACKAGE UNLINK: defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py37_0 <===
  prefix=D:\Anaconda3


done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 1079, in run_script
    subprocess_call(command_args, env=env, path=dirname(path))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\subprocess.py", line 85, in subprocess_call
    output=formatted_output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', '/d', '/c', 'D:\\Anaconda3\\.tmpsme8hq3b.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 649, in _execute_post_link_actions
    activate=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 1095, in run_script
    raise LinkError(message)
conda.exceptions.LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 558, in _execute
    cls._execute_post_link_actions(pkg_idx_tracked, axngroup)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 664, in _execute_post_link_actions
    reverse_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'update')
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 275, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 304, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 241, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 587, in _execute
    rollback_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-5.1.1-py37h39e3cac_0
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I uninstalled my existing python 3.7 and anaconda. I re-installed anaconda with one key difference.

I registered Anaconda as my default Python 3.7 during the Anaconda installation. This lets visual studio, PyDev and other programs automatically detect Anaconda as the primary version to use.

Problem was similar to this:
[Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701359/running-setup-py-install-for-fbprophet-error)