# PyStan successfully installed via PIP, but I have bug with IMPORT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, data-science, pystan

Getting `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` while trying to import pystan.

After installing and uninstaling pystan from several resources, I can easily do `pip install`, but I can't import it in Jupyter notebook.

```
import pystan
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-ca8618bb8e4a> in <module>
----> 1 import pystan

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py in <module>
      7 import logging
      8 
----> 9 from pystan.api import stanc, stan
     10 from pystan.misc import read_rdump, stan_rdump, stansummary
     11 from pystan.diagnostics import check_hmc_diagnostics

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py in <module>
     11 import os
     12 
---> 13 import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
     14 from pystan._compat import string_types, PY2
     15 from pystan.model import StanModel

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Look at https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1088

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701359/running-setup-py-install-for-fbprophet-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpystan%5D+ImportError%3A+DLL+load+failed%3A+The+specified+module+could+not+be+found.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64713567/10126125