# How to successfully install fbprophet via Gitlab CI?

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, gitlab-ci, facebook-prophet

I am trying to deploy a code of mine (that uses fbprophet) as an EC2 instance using Gitlab CI.

my `requirements.txt` file:

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
cmdstanpy==0.4
convertdate==2.2.1
cycler==0.10.0
cython==0.29.21; python_version >= '2.6' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
ephem==3.7.7.1
fbprophet==0.6
holidays==0.10.3
joblib==0.16.0; python_version >= '3.6'
kiwisolver==1.2.0; python_version >= '3.6'
korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
lunarcalendar==0.0.9; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version < '4'
matplotlib==3.3.0; python_version >= '3.6'
numpy==1.19.1
pandas==1.0.5
pillow==7.2.0; python_version >= '3.5'
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pymeeus==0.3.7
pyparsing==2.4.7; python_version >= '2.6' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
pystan==2.19.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
pytz==2020.1
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.5.2; python_version >= '3.6'
setuptools-git==1.2
six==1.15.0; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
sqlalchemy==1.3.18
threadpoolctl==2.1.0; python_version >= '3.5'
```

When the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    S3_TEST_BUCKET: $BUCKET_UNPACK

stages:
    - deploy 

packageAndDeploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install gcc g++ build-essential
    - apt-get -y install python3-pip python3.7 zip python3.7-dev
    - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - python3.7 -V
    - pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt
```

**It runs successfully**

```
$ pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.4
  Downloading cmdstanpy-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting convertdate==2.2.1
  Downloading convertdate-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting cycler==0.10.0
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting cython==0.29.21
  Downloading Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting ephem==3.7.7.1
  Downloading ephem-3.7.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting fbprophet==0.6
  Downloading fbprophet-0.6.tar.gz (54 kB)
Collecting holidays==0.10.3
  Downloading holidays-0.10.3.tar.gz (114 kB)
Collecting joblib==0.16.0
  Downloading joblib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (300 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.2.0
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88 kB)
Collecting korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
  Downloading korean_lunar_calendar-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 kB)
Collecting lunarcalendar==0.0.9
  Downloading LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.0
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.0-1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.1
  Downloading numpy-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
Collecting pandas==1.0.5
  Downloading pandas-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.1 MB)
Collecting pillow==7.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
Collecting pymeeus==0.3.7
  Downloading PyMeeus-0.3.7.tar.gz (732 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pystan==2.19.1.1
  Downloading pystan-2.19.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (67.3 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting pytz==2020.1
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn==0.23.1
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.23.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Collecting scipy==1.5.2
  Downloading scipy-1.5.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
Collecting setuptools-git==1.2
  Downloading setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting six==1.15.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy==1.3.18
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.18-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting threadpoolctl==2.1.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet, holidays, pymeeus
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-c5ch2465
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/fbprophet
  creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/setup.py", line 148, in <module>
      """
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 204, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
      build_models(target_dir)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
      from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
    File "/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/fbprophet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
    File "/tmp/pip-install-upo5plzy/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 14, in <module>
      import numpy as np
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for holidays: filename=holidays-0.10.3-py3-none-any.whl size=122264 sha256=d9a0eb199d8421b97d7a17d173acfa998d9feeac4da85ae5eac7452e2a52e54e
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d0/67/01/18308fa32fabcd0af569b9f52934b2118c9b30bcf7b4b378f8
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pymeeus: filename=PyMeeus-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl size=691116 sha256=ca5c9777c09575d57de0d69f0f3a2e1328c84d67bd05a1c1f11ad308811ea5be
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/80/32/5f/2a67880d4ce584b9cf99146f9945e46942dfb010a9382c6ff5
Successfully built holidays pymeeus
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas, cmdstanpy, pymeeus, convertdate, cycler, cython, ephem, lunarcalendar, korean-lunar-calendar, holidays, pyparsing, pillow, kiwisolver, matplotlib, pystan, setuptools-git, fbprophet, joblib, psycopg2-binary, threadpoolctl, scipy, scikit-learn, sqlalchemy
  Attempting uninstall: six
    Found existing installation: six 1.11.0
    Uninstalling six-1.11.0:
      Successfully uninstalled six-1.11.0
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: started
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: still running...
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed cmdstanpy-0.4.0 convertdate-2.2.1 cycler-0.10.0 cython-0.29.21 ephem-3.7.7.1 fbprophet-0.6 holidays-0.10.3 joblib-0.16.0 kiwisolver-1.2.0 korean-lunar-calendar-0.2.1 lunarcalendar-0.0.9 matplotlib-3.3.0 numpy-1.19.1 pandas-1.0.5 pillow-7.2.0 psycopg2-binary-2.8.5 pymeeus-0.3.7 pyparsing-2.4.7 pystan-2.19.1.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 scikit-learn-0.23.1 scipy-1.5.2 setuptools-git-1.2 six-1.15.0 sqlalchemy-1.3.18 threadpoolctl-2.1.0
Job succeeded
```

But when I change the CI file to (for deploying on AWS):

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    S3_TEST_BUCKET: $BUCKET_UNPACK

stages:
    - deploy 

packageAndDeploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install gcc g++ build-essential
    - apt-get -y install python3-pip python3.7 zip python3.7-dev
    - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - python3.7 -V
    - pip3.7 install virtualenv
    - mv iso_forest_ad.py ~
    - mv requirements.txt ~

    # Setup virtual environment
    - mkdir ~/forEC2
    #- mv package ~/forEC2
    - cd ~/forEC2
    - virtualenv -p python3.7 venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3.7 install -r ~/requirements.txt -t ~/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

    # Package environment and dependencies
    - cd ~/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
    - zip -r9 ~/forEC2/archive.zip .
    - cd ~
    - zip -g ~/forEC2/archive.zip iso_forest_ad.py

    # Install AWS CLI
    - pip install awscli --upgrade
    - export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin

    # Configure AWS connection
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_TEST_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_TEST_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account'
    - aws s3 cp ~/forEC2/archive.zip $BUCKET_UNPACK/xyz.zip
```

It throws the following error:

```
$ pip3.7 install -r ~/requirements.txt -t ~/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.4
  Downloading cmdstanpy-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting convertdate==2.2.1
  Downloading convertdate-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting cycler==0.10.0
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting cython==0.29.21
  Downloading Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting ephem==3.7.7.1
  Downloading ephem-3.7.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting fbprophet==0.6
  Downloading fbprophet-0.6.tar.gz (54 kB)
Collecting holidays==0.10.3
  Downloading holidays-0.10.3.tar.gz (114 kB)
Collecting joblib==0.16.0
  Downloading joblib-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (300 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.2.0
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88 kB)
Collecting korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
  Downloading korean_lunar_calendar-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 kB)
Collecting lunarcalendar==0.0.9
  Downloading LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.0
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.0-1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.1
  Downloading numpy-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
Collecting pandas==1.0.5
  Downloading pandas-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.1 MB)
Collecting pillow==7.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
Collecting pymeeus==0.3.7
  Downloading PyMeeus-0.3.7.tar.gz (732 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pystan==2.19.1.1
  Downloading pystan-2.19.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (67.3 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting pytz==2020.1
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn==0.23.1
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.23.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Collecting scipy==1.5.2
  Downloading scipy-1.5.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
Collecting setuptools-git==1.2
  Downloading setuptools_git-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting six==1.15.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy==1.3.18
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.18-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting threadpoolctl==2.1.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet, holidays, pymeeus
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /root/forEC2/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-mfybmls1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/fbprophet
  creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 148, in <module>
      """
    File "/root/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/root/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
      build_models(target_dir)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
      from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
    File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/fbprophet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
    File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 14, in <module>
      import numpy as np
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for holidays (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for holidays: filename=holidays-0.10.3-py3-none-any.whl size=115855 sha256=7a285975b4ee67336ed9f72ba86938bc50e0525828c6c4a0ee23f89d2a4138ca
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d0/67/01/18308fa32fabcd0af569b9f52934b2118c9b30bcf7b4b378f8
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pymeeus: filename=PyMeeus-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl size=702876 sha256=cc24a563f61d172dca5e377cff86172e162429e1330621cb6534ca1f7d964bb9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/80/32/5f/2a67880d4ce584b9cf99146f9945e46942dfb010a9382c6ff5
Successfully built holidays pymeeus
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas, cmdstanpy, pymeeus, convertdate, cycler, cython, ephem, pystan, pillow, pyparsing, kiwisolver, matplotlib, lunarcalendar, korean-lunar-calendar, holidays, setuptools-git, fbprophet, joblib, psycopg2-binary, scipy, threadpoolctl, scikit-learn, sqlalchemy
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: started
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /root/forEC2/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oymqs6p3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --home /tmp/pip-target-2bx5n0o4 --compile --install-headers /root/forEC2/venv/include/site/python3.7/fbprophet
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/
    Complete output (42 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/fbprophet
    creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 148, in <module>
        """
      File "/root/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/root/forEC2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
        build_models(target_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
        from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/fbprophet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 14, in <module>
        import numpy as np
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /root/forEC2/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eq1vplr2/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oymqs6p3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --home /tmp/pip-target-2bx5n0o4 --compile --install-headers /root/forEC2/venv/include/site/python3.7/fbprophet Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: try to install the `build-essential` package

Comment: @SergioTanaka Already did, but still throws the same error

Comment: @Junkrat can you try to install fbprophet as a separate package like with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701443/2572645) through the CI?

Comment: @AndyK Hey, how can I run the `conda` commands? Isn't it used for anaconda?

Comment: Just install `numpy` separately before the requirements install; add a `pip3.7 install numpy` command before the `pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt` invocation.

Comment: @hoefling Hey, I will try that, but the `requirements.txt` already has `numpy` in it.

Comment: I know. The problem here seems to be that `fbprophet` imports `numpy` in its setup script, so adding `numpy` to requirements won't solve the issue. The process is roughly the following: `pip` reads package names from reqs file; downloads the dists from PyPI; for any source dist, a wheel is being built (this is where the error happens); all wheels are being installed (this is where `numpy` is actually installed).

Comment: @hoefling Thank you for the explanation. I ended up installing all the dependencies mentioned in the `requirements.txt` of fbprophet (`pip3.7 install Cython numpy pandas convertdate LunarCalendar holidays setuptools-git python-dateutil tqdm pystan matplotlib LunarCalendar`) and now it works.

Comment: @hoefling If you can make it as the answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with `fbprophet` is that it imports and executes its own code in `setup.py`. This is sometimes called a "race condition", although it has nothing to do with concurrency - one has to be careful about importing code which is in the process of being installed.

Here, `fbprophet.models` imported in `setup.py` triggers import of `fbprophet.forecaster` (even if unused) via `fbprophet/__init__.py`, which triggers the imports of `numpy`, `pandas` etc. None of the packages is declared as build dependency via `setup_requires`, thus the error. To avoid it, you have to install the dependencies in a separate command before installing your own requirements:

```
- pip3.7 install numpy pandas ...
- pip3.7 install -r ~/requirements.txt
```

The list of `fbprophet`'s requirements can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/0d260699e4776c449703a957f08eca8013461a47/python/requirements.txt) (although you've already figured it out in the comments).